# Parse array of json objects into a particular format of array of json as per requirement in project

Tags: javascript, json

based on my requiremrnt in my project i am getting the below array of json as input but i need to convert that into a particular format of array of json object.

```
[
  {
    "accident_description": "bike accident",
    "reported_by": "john",

  },
   {
    "accident_description": "car accident",
    "reported_by": "sam",

  }
]
```

output>>>

```
  "fields": [
    {
      "title": "accident_description",
      "values": "bike accident"
      "type": "generic",

    },
    {
      "title": "reported_by",
      "values": "john",
      "type": "generic",

    },
    {
      "title": "accident_description",
      "values": "car accident"
      "type": "generic",

    },
    {
      "title": "reported_by",
      "values": "sam",
      "type": "generic",

    },
  ]
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far

Comment: to answer the question you deleted (which wasn't really a duplicate of this, just the next step in *your* code) ... `arr.flatMap(o=>Object.entries(o).flatMap(([k,v],i)=>[{title:k,values:v,type:'generic'}].concat(i%2?[{title:'title1',values:'value1',type:'type1'},{title:'title2',values:'value2',type:'type2'}]:[])));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and `map()`.

- Inside `flatMap()` get the entries of object using `Object.entires()`
- Then apply `map()` on the entries and return an object.

```js
const arr = [ { "accident_description": "bike accident", "reported_by": "john", }, { "accident_description": "car accident", "reported_by": "sam", } ];

let res = arr.flatMap(x => (Object.entries(x).map(([k,v]) => ({title:k,values:v,type:"generic"}))));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [`Object.entires`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of each object like this:

```js
const input=[{"accident_description":"bike accident","reported_by":"john",},{"accident_description":"car accident","reported_by":"sam",}],
      type = "generic";

const output = input.flatMap(Object.entries)
                    .map(([title, values]) => ({ title, values, type }))
     
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the reduce function to get the desired output :-

```
[
  {
    "accident_description": "bike accident",
    "reported_by": "john",

  },
   {
    "accident_description": "car accident",
    "reported_by": "sam",

  }
].reduce((arr,item) => {
    for(let key in item){
        arr.push({
            "title" : key,
            "values" : item[key],
            "type"  : "generic"
        });
    }
    return arr;

},[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` to loop thru the array. Use `Object.entries` to convert each object into an array and `map` to return the desired object.

```js
let arr = [{"accident_description":"bike accident","reported_by":"john"},{"accident_description":"car accident","reported_by":"sam"}];

let result = arr.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o).map(([v, k]) => ({"title": v,"values": k,"type": "generic"})))

console.log(result);
```

...Or you can also use `concat` instead of `flatMap`

```js
let arr = [{"accident_description":"bike accident","reported_by":"john"},{"accident_description":"car accident","reported_by":"sam"}];

let result = [].concat(...arr.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o).map(([v, k]) => ({"title": v,"values": k,"type": "generic"}))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve what you want to do

flatMap instead of map will create flat array from looping over your input. i.e. your first obj from input array will become two obj in output array. So insted of merging the two objects in one array flatMap will make it flat i.e. two separate entries. Then use reduce and concat to format data from one obj.

```js
const input = [{
    "accident_description": "bike accident",
    "reported_by": "john",

  },
  {
    "accident_description": "car accident",
    "reported_by": "sam",

  }
]

const out = input.flatMap(obj =>
  Object.keys(obj)
  .reduce((acc, cur) =>
    acc.concat({
      title: cur,
      values: obj[cur],
      type: "dynamic"
    }), [])
)

console.log(out)
```